# ASP.Net Web Forms Friendly URLs not working on server

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Friendly URLs for new ASP.Net Web Forms project works great debugging on my computer but when published to server it doesn't work do I need to change something in IIS to get this to work on the server?

Comment: Do you have the Application Pool set to Integrated Pipeline?

Comment: Yes ManagedPipelineMode is set to Integrated not Classic

Comment: What is the error message and which version of IIS is it?

Comment: Get typical 404 message and it's IIS7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had the same problem with Bundles and found I needed to add this to the system.webServer section of the web.config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: for me it is not working when i copy code paste in my web.config i was getting error related to System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule and then i have resolved the error then also urls not working for me. Please help me.

Comment: i have de same problem it not work at all . i think it is i have not install System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule